# swipe refresh is overriding scrolling the menu in my web page in webview

Tags: java, android-studio, android-webview, swiperefreshlayout

I'm setting up a web page inside web view. my web page have swipe down to refresh function.when my web page is in top, when i scroll drawer menu in my web page , swipe to refresh is occurring. how to solve this issue?

**main activity layout code**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/swipe">

        <WebView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/homeWeb"
            android:layout_above="@id/navBar"/>


</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener(){        
  @Override           
  public void onRefresh() {          
    homeWeb.reload();              
  }      
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable/Disable swipe refresh when do something with webview.
Below method do same. try and let me know will it work or not.

```
swipe.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollChanged() {
                    swipe.setEnabled((homeWeb.getScrollY() == 0));
                }
            });
```

Comment: Note that this won't work if you have a horizontal scrolling component at the top of your webpage because the WebView scroll y will be at 0.